# Subgroup generated by elements of finite order

Tags: group-theory

Let G be any group and let H be the subgroup of G generated by all elements of finite order. Is there a name for H?

Comment: Sorta seems like it would be the group generated by the torsion subset. I say torsion *subset* rather than *subgroup* because the set of finite elements isn't necessarily a subgroup in nonabelian groups.

Comment: I have never heard of a name for this subgroup. If the torsion elements do form a subgroup, then it is called the torsion subgroup.